# Implicit Partial Differentiation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, laplacian

So this is a question that should be very easy but I can't do this. My knowledge of basic differentiation of partial derivatives aren't working. Can anyone help me how to do **a and b**. What I tried was the obvious take $r$ as the function of $x$ and $\theta$ and then differentiate, which doesn't work. Then I am thinking of doing implicit differentiation, which I'm not sure how to do based on the formulas I see. Thanks for your time.

[image]

Comment: What *does not work* when you write $r$ as a function of $theta$?

Comment: r = x / cos theta, which when diffrentiated partially wrt x, is 1 / cos theta.

Comment: That is not true, as $\theta$ is a function of $x$. Please use [LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here.

Answer (score 0):

We have $x= r \cos \theta$, $y= r \sin \theta$. We know that $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Therefore $$\frac{dr}{dx} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2x = \frac{x}{r} = \frac{r\cos\theta}{r} = \cos\theta.$$

You can solve the other tasks quite similarly.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do e?